# Вызов метода внутри конструктора

Tags: php

У меня есть вот такой код

```php
 $timer = new UXAnimationTimer(function () {
    $i += 1;
    $this->phantom_border->x -= $i;
    $this->phantom_border->width += $i*2;

    if ($i >= 20) {
        // остановка
    }
});

$timer->start();
```

Могу ли я как-нибудь вызвать метод $timer->stop(); внутри этой функции на месте, где написано 'остановка'?

Comment: `$this->stop()`?

Comment: @u_mulder unable to call method. $this указывает на класс, в котором находится функция с этим кодом

Comment: а может `return`, не?

Comment: уже нормально ответили - вопрос решили через use

Comment: Если вы решили задачу - опубликуйте ответ, помогите другим пользователям.

Comment: use($timer) после function () решило проблему